# Can you say "a person exits x into y"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

The specific sentence is "Following the maid, they exited the mansion grounds, and into the forest beyond."

In English, does chaining "exited" with "and into" in this way make sense?

As a bonus, is there any issue with the formulation of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**exited into** is fine, but *exited and into* doesn't make sense.

*Exit* means "to go out of or leave a place".  This is why *exited (X) into* makes sense; people are leaving wherever they were and going into something else.  For example,

> [Father Leo exited the building into the din of early morning traffic.](https://books.google.com/books?id=16hua5kWXVUC&pg=PA71&dq=%22exited%20the%20building%20into%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihhsiFxab7AhXcjYkEHTtQDGQQ6AF6BAgCEAI)

But *exited and into* doesn't make sense.  If I read this, I would say "OK, the person exited, and then they...*into*?"  I would expect *and* to be followed by another verb, like "They exited the palace and *mounted their horses*", or a completely different clause, like "They exited the palace and the king breathed a sigh of relief."

Comment: Not sure how this got checked and my answer got downvoted (not bitter at all) but I definitely disagree. "They exited the mansion and into the forest" is entirely proper. I agree that sometimes it may be more natural to omit the "and", but in the original example, which I notice you didn't use, the "and" works well (although the comma, as I noted in my answer, doesn't). If you google "exited the building and into" in quotes, you'll get plenty of hits.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it's fine. One could say, "they exited into the forest grounds," with the location being exited implied but not explicitly stated. It follows that it makes sense to chain the two actions together, as you term it. No need to repeat the verb.

However, it would be preferable to omit the second comma.